# Display a Two-Level Unordered List Rows

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'd like to use a two-level unordered list to create rows of inline options.

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li>CHOICE ONE
        <ul class="children">
            <li>option a</li>
            <li>option b</li>
            <li>option c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>CHOICE TWO
        <ul class="children">
            <li>option d</li>
            <li>option e</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>CHOICE THREE</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like it to display like this:

> CHOICE ONE option a option b option c 
>   CHOICE TWO option d option e 
>   CHOICE THREE

How can I do this in CSS?  I do not have the ability to add custom IDs or Classes to the UL or LI tags.

Thank you!

Comment: If you can't add IDS or classes the CSS you make may override lists everywhere on the page. You need at least a custom class name or ID on the wrapping element.

Comment: I do have a <div> around this block with its own ID <div id="menu">.

Comment: I've tried using display:inline on the li element and ul.children, but I end up either getting everything in one long row, or having just the second level list items shown inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li ul, ul ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**See** [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/qxDu2/1/)

Comment: Thank you! This worked just how I was hoping.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul, li {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
ul ul, ul ul li {display:inline;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e7hAF/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul li {display: block;}
ul li ul li {display: inline;}
.children {display: inline; padding-left: 0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>CHOICE ONE
        <ul class="children">
            <li>option a</li>
            <li>option b</li>
            <li>option c</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>CHOICE TWO
        <ul class="children">
            <li>option d</li>
            <li>option e</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>CHOICE THREE</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```